# What is the difference between globally deployed and local host deployed

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

i am currently created a visual web part i just added a button in the webpart and run the application . after deploying the application by pressing f5 when i open central administration under manage form solution  i can see the webpart is been deployed but its deployed as "http://machinename" instead of globally deployed. i have also deployed by using power shell also where it also shows the same .

my requirement is that i should get deployed my web part in globally and what is the difference between globally deployed and http://machinename.

can any one help me out.

regards,
Zakeer Ahamed.S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A global WSP package does not contain any resources for the local IIS web site folder such as BIN assemblies, resource files or web.config changes. So if a package contains one or more files for the IIS folder somewhere under Inetpub it is considered a local package. When deploying a global package it will be deployed to all servers in the farm. This is different for local packages. A URL must be specified and it is only deployed to front end servers that run the web application that is being deployed to.

Therefore you cannot deploy webparts or controls globally because these require a SafeControl entry in web.config.